# where like and order by on different tables/columns

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

For information, on the following examples, `big_table` is composed of millions of rows and `small_table` of hundreds.

Here is the basic query i'm trying to do:

```
SELECT b.id 
    FROM big_table b 
    LEFT JOIN small_table s 
    ON b.small_id=s.id
    WHERE s.name like 'something%' 
    ORDER BY b.name 
    LIMIT 10, 10;
```

This is slow and I can understand why both index can't be used.

My initial idea was to split the query into parts.

This is fast:

```
SELECT id FROM small_table WHERE name like 'something%';
```

This is also fast:

```
SELECT id FROM big_table WHERE small_id IN (1, 2) ORDER BY name LIMIT 10, 10;
```

But, put together, it becomes slow:

```
SELECT id FROM big_table 
    WHERE small_id 
    IN (
        SELECT id 
        FROM small_table WHERE name like 'something%'
    ) 
    ORDER BY name 
    LIMIT 10, 10;
```

Unless the subquery is re-evaluated for every row, it shouldn't be slower than executing both query separately right?

I'm looking for any help optimizing the initial query and understanding why the second one doesn't work.

---

EXPLAIN result for the last query :

```
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows  | Extra
| 1 | PRIMARY | small_table | range | PRIMARY, ix_small_name | ix_small_name | 768 | NULL | 1 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | big_table | ref | ix_join_foreign_key   | ix_join_foreign_key | 9 | small_table.id | 11870 | |
```

---

**temporary solution :**

```
SELECT id FROM big_table ignore index(ix_join_foreign_key)
    WHERE small_id 
    IN (
        SELECT id 
        FROM small_table ignore index(PRIMARY)
        WHERE name like 'something%'
    ) 
    ORDER BY name 
    LIMIT 10, 10;
```

(result & explain is the same with an EXISTS instead of IN)

EXPLAIN output becomes:

```
| 1 | PRIMARY | big_table | index  | NULL | ix_big_name | 768 | NULL | 20 | |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <subquery2> | eq_ref | distinct_key | distinct_key | 8 | func | 1 | |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | small_table | range | ix_small_name | ix_small_name | 768 | NULL | 1 | Using where; Using index |
```

if anyone has a better solution, I'm still interested.

Comment: how does the execution plan look like for the last query?

Comment: is `ix_small_name` an index based on `big_table.small_id` ?

Comment: ON b.small_ids.id ? and your tables, what are they like?

Comment: @MaxU no, it's an index based on small_table.name (which is a varchar)

Comment: @e4c5 sorry typo, b.small_id=d.id.

Comment: You are wrong assuming that a combined query should not be slower then the sum of the two single queries. Reading a table is always rather fast (depending on its size of course), but combining two tables, i.e. find a match for each record in a table in the other table is quite a task and can take long.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` in your first query makes no sense. Why outer join? That would mean: give me the b record regardless of any match in s. But then your `WHERE` clause dismisses outer-joined records anyway turning the join into an `INNER JOIN` anyway. So this *is* effectively an `INNER JOIN`, hence call it thus. But as you are looking for mere existence, you should use `EXISTS` or `IN` anyway. MySQL is known for being weak on `IN` (and least that was the case for a long time and may still be so), so `EXISTS` may be the best bet here.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner But since the inner query is constant / independant of the row being scanned, it shouldn't matter no? Right now I could sequentially execute both queries and get the correct result (very fast), why can't mysql figure this out?

Comment: No. The query must look up every record in b whether it has a match in s. So read b + read s + loop through b and s the find the matches. The loop is what takes most of the time.

Comment: So in my code I should simply execute both query separately? I find it very strange that there is no way to get the same behavior in a single query.

Comment: You are right, I was confused. Obviously the DBMS doesn't know whether it will find just a couple or hundreds of IDs with the small_table query. So it generates a compromise plan that would work for both scenarios (whereas the plan that is great for only two IDs would probably run extremely long for many IDs). So yes, either run the queries separately or give the DBMS a hint (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html). Look at the execution plan for the quick big_table query and try to force the same approach on the combined query.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation/link. I managed to make it work. If you are interested, I had to put `ignore index(PRIMARY)` in the inner query and `ignore index (ix_join_foreign_key)` in the outer query. `ix_join_foreign_key` is the foreign key that points to small_table.id. Now it creates an additional materialized view containing the result of the inner query and the select on big_table is free to use it's own index for the order by. Feel free to edit your initial answer with what you said and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is that you have conditions on the small table but are trying to avoid a sort in the large table.  In MySQL, I think you need to do at least a full table scan.

One step is to write the query using `exists`, as others have mentioned:

```
SELECT b.id
FROM big_table b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM small_table s
              WHERE s.name LIKE 'something%' AND s.id = b.small_id
             )
ORDER BY b.name;
```

The question is:  Can you trick MySQL into doing the `ORDER BY` using an index?  One possibility is to use the appropriate index.  In this case, the appropriate index is:  `big_table(name, small_id, id)` and `small_table(id, name)`.  The ordering of the keys in the index is important.  Because the first is a covering index, MySQL might read through the index in order by name, choosing the appropriate ids.

Comment: this works as long as I force the use of `small_table(id, name)`. Otherwise the `small_table(name)` is used, and if removed, big table uses the foreign key as an index and not `big_table(name, small_id, id)`. Would you mind checking my other solution in the original question? It doesn't require creating more indexes, but I'm not sure what is better (or why).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an `EXISTS` or `IN` query. As MySQL is known to be weak on `IN` I'd try `EXISTS` in spite of liking `IN` better for its simplicity.

```
select id
from big_table b
where exists
(
  select *
  from small_table s
  where s.id = b.small_id
  and s.name = 'something%'
)
order by name 
limit 10, 10;
```

It would be helpful to have a good index on `big_table`. It should first contain the `small_id` to find the match, then the `name` for the sorting. The ID is automatically included in MySQL indexes, as far as I know (otherwise it should also be added to the index). So thus you'd have an index containing all fields needed from `big_table` (that is called a covering index) in the desired order, so all data can be read from the index alone and the table itself doesn't have to get accessed.

```
create index idx_big_quick on big_table(small_id, name);
```

Comment: tried it, but it doesn't help. The problem is still the `order by name`. Mysql use your idx_big_quick index for the where exists/where in and then does a filesort without using the proper index. Which is obviously extremely slow.

Comment: That is strange. Why does MySQL read the table when everything is in the index? Maybe I was wrong about the ID being automatically part of the index. You can please try adding it? `create index idx_big_quick on big_table(small_id, name, id);`

Comment: still the same. Check the explain result in my question (it's the same with `idx_big_quick` instead of `ix_join_foreign_key`). What I find weird is why is the `using filesort` on the `small_table` line and not `big table`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT b.id
FROM big_table b
JOIN small_table s
  ON b.small_id = s.id
WHERE s.name like 'something%'
ORDER BY b.name;
```

or

```
SELECT b.id FROM big_table b
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM small_table s
             WHERE s.name LIKE 'something%' AND s.id = b.small_id)
ORDER BY b.name;
```

NOTE: you don't seem to need `LEFT JOIN`. Left outer join will almost always result in full table scan of the `big_table`

PS make sure you have an index on `big_table.small_id`

Comment: you removed the ORDER BY, it is what makes the query slow. I need it.

You're right about the LEFT JOIN, but removing it doesn't really help.

Comment: @user1278743, i guess `left join` - made your query slow

Comment: I removed it, it doesn't change anything. mysql still does a filesort on big_table.name (even though an index is available).

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A**

```
SELECT  b.id
    FROM  big_table b
    JOIN  small_table s  ON b.small_id=s.id
    WHERE  s.name like 'something%'
    ORDER BY  b.name
    LIMIT  10, 10;
```

(Note removal of `LEFT`.)

You need

```
small_table:  INDEX(name, id)
big_table:    INDEX(small_id), or, for 'covering': INDEX(small_id, name, id)
```

It will use the `s` index to find `'something%'` and walk through.  But it must find all such rows, and `JOIN` to `b` to find all such rows there.  Only then can it do the `ORDER BY`, `OFFSET`, and `LIMIT`.  There *will* be a filesort (which *may* happen in RAM).

The column order in the indexes is important.

**Plan B**

The other suggestion *may* work well; it depends on various things.

```
SELECT  b.id
    FROM  big_table b
    WHERE  EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  small_table s
            WHERE  s.name LIKE 'something%'
              AND  s.id = b.small_id 
      )
    ORDER BY  b.name
    LIMIT 10, 10;
```

That needs these:

```
big_table:    INDEX(name), or for 'covering',  INDEX(name, small_id, id)
small_table:  INDEX(id, name), which is 'covering'
```

(Caveat:  If you are doing something other than `SELECT b.id`, my comments about covering may be wrong.)

Which is faster (A or B)?  Cannot predict without understanding the frequency of 'something%' and how 'many' the many-to-1 mapping is.

**Settings**

If these tables are InnoDB, then be sure that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set to about 70% of *available* RAM.

**Pagination**

Your use of `OFFSET` implies that you are 'paging' through the data?  `OFFSET` is an inefficient way to do it.  See [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) on such, but note that only Plan B will work with it.